# is it possible to use a variable to reference a .NET static class in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a lot of System.IO.Path operations and I was curious if it was possible to store reference to that static class in a variable so it is shorter?

Instead of writing these long winded namespace.class paths:

```
[System.IO.Path]::Combine([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($targetFile), [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName("newfile_$targetFile"))
```

It would be great to write this:

```
$path = [System.IO.Path]
$path.Combine($path.GetDirectoryName($targetFile), $path.GetFileName("newfile_$targetFile"))
```

Is there a way to do this in powershell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Your suggested code is close, you just need use the `::` static invocation syntax:

```
$path = [System.IO.Path]
$path::Combine( ... )
```

Comment: nice, didnt know that!

Comment: Ahh awesome. I tried this but the ISE didn't give me any intellesense so I just assumed it was invalid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell has built-in cmdlets for some path operations:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-command -Noun Path
CommandType Name         ModuleName                     
----------- ----         ----------                     
Cmdlet      Convert-Path Microsoft.Powershell.Management
Cmdlet      Join-Path    Microsoft.Powershell.Management
Cmdlet      Resolve-Path Microsoft.Powershell.Management
Cmdlet      Split-Path   Microsoft.Powershell.Management
Cmdlet      Test-Path    Microsoft.Powershell.Management
```

Your example implemented with native PowerShell cmdlets:

```
Join-Path (Split-Path $targetFile) (Split-Path $targetFile -Leaf)
```

Comment: I'm still interested in if you can or can't do this, but I adjusted my example to pull filename also. Perhaps you adjust your example?

Comment: I edited my answer. Split-Path with -Leaf parameter gives you the file name